# Posting an action works... but no image

Tags: facebook, image, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

I'm able to post an open graph action to facebook using the following url:

https://graph.facebook.com/me/video.watches

with the following post data:

video=http://eqnetwork.com/home/video.html?f=8e7b4f27-8cbd-4430-84df-d9ccb46da45f.mp4

[link to an image http://www.brianrice.com/downloads/actionpost.png](http://www.brianrice.com/downloads/actionpost.png)

It seems to be getting the title from the open graph metatags at the "video" object. But, it's not getting the image (even though one is specified in the metatag "og:image").

Also, if I add this to the post data:

picture=http://eqnetwork.com/icons/mgen/overplayThumbnail.ms?drid=14282&subType=ljpg&w=120&h=120&o=1&thumbnail=

still no image.

Any thoughts?

- Brian

Comment: It's cutting out the `=` most likely because it's expecting a parameter after `=` You could call it a bug... I guess, but why have code that accepts the `thumbnail` parameter that way :/

Comment: The url's work as they are... it's just that facebook is not utilizing them... you are allowed to have "no value" after a parameter.

Comment: But... you're right... when I run the video url through the facebook debugger... the image is blank... when I look at the url for the image... the '=' is stripped off... and that's causing the url to fail!

Comment: glad u figured it out. i need some road map on how to submit actions. do u have any tutorials or docs you would recommend. When i try to submit the actions, i m getting an error saying, i have to puslish at least one action.

Comment: You need to actually have your code post an action to Facebook so it shows up in your "Activity Log" on Facebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what i m getting after testing with facebook debugger:

```
developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http%3A%2F%2Feqnetwork.com%2Ficons%2Fmgen%2FoverplayThumbnail.ms%3Fdrid%3D15162%26subType%3Dljpg%26w%3D120%26h%3D120%26o%3D1%26thumbnail%3D
```

below is the scraped url. so obviously there is a CDN error.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<b>06/12/2012 15:33:12 ***** CDNMGEN2 reported an error *****</b><br><br><tt>
MRL: /mgen/overplayThumbnail.ms?drid=15162&amp;subType=ljpg&amp;w=120&amp;h=120&amp;o=1&amp;thumbnail<br><br>
A filter error occurred while processing '/mgen/overplayThumbnail.ms?drid=15162&amp;subType=ljpg&amp;w=120&amp;h=120&amp;o=1&amp;thumbnail':<br>Missing value for overplayThumbnail.ms?drid=15162&amp;subType=ljpg&amp;w=120&amp;h=120&amp;o=1&amp;thumbnail at thumbnail</tt>
</head></html>
```

This is complaning about the thumbnail value which shoudl be provided.

Comment: As noted above: When I run the video url through the facebook debugger... the image is blank... when I look at the url for the image... the '=' is stripped off... and that's causing the url to fail!